# Passing props through multiple components (four), parent State not updating

Tags: reactjs

I have a React ecommerce site that is currently integrated with Stripe. When a successful payment is submitted, the cart is emptied (managed in localStorage), however the Cart quantity in the Navbar isn't resetting to 0.

The cart quantity is being managed in state in the `<App />` component, `setQty`. The stripe payment is submitted in the `<PaymentForm>` component which is nested 4 components deep:

`<App />` > `<Checkout />` > `<PaymentForm />` > `<CheckoutForm />`

In `CheckoutForm`, I'm using `setQty({quantity: 0});` which I thought would pass "0" up to `<App />` and reset the Cart quantity, instead I get an error of "Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): setQty is not a function". Why is this? How can I get this to work? Also, is there an easier way of resetting the Cart without passing props through so many components?

A breakdown of each component so you can see how I'm passing setQty through each component:

**App**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Nav from './Nav';
import Shop from './Components/Shop';
import Info from './Components/Info';
import Cart from './Components/Cart';
import Item from './Components/Item';
import Checkout from './Components/CheckoutForm/Checkout';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import { getQuantity } from './helpers/helperTools';

function App() {
    const storageItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('product'));
    const [qty, setQty] = useState({quantity: getQuantity(storageItems || [])});
    console.log("Apppp", qty)

    return (
      <Router>
        <div className="App">
          <Nav qty={qty.quantity} />

          <Route path="/" exact component={Shop} />
          <Route path="/Info" component={Info} />
          <Route path="/Cart/" render={(props) => <Cart {...props} setQty={setQty} />} />
          <Route path="/Item/:item" component={Item} />
          <Route path="/Checkout" component={Checkout} setQty={setQty} />

        </div>
      </Router>
    )
}

export default App;
```

**Checkout**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import {
  Paper,
  Stepper,
  Step,
  StepLabel,
  Typography,
  CircularProgress,
  Divider,
  Button,
} from '@material-ui/core';

import useStyles from './styles';
import AddressForm from './AddressForm';
import PaymentForm from './PaymentForm';

const steps = ['Shipping address', 'Payment details'];

function Checkout({setQty}) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [activeStep, setActiveStep] = useState(0);
  const [shippingData, setShippingData] = useState({});

  const nextStep = () => setActiveStep((prevActiveStep) => prevActiveStep + 1);
  const backStep = () => setActiveStep((prevActiveStep) => prevActiveStep - 1);

  const next = (data) => {
    setShippingData(data);

    nextStep();
  };

  const Form = () =>
    activeStep === 0 ? (
      <AddressForm next={next} />
    ) : (
      <PaymentForm shippingData={shippingData} backStep={backStep} nextStep={nextStep} setQty={setQty} />
    );

  const Confirmation = () => <div>Confirmation</div>;

  return (
    <div>
      <div className={classes.toolbar} />
      <main className={classes.layout}>
        <Paper className={classes.paper}>
          <Typography variant='h4' align='center'>
            Checkout
          </Typography>
          <Stepper activeStep={activeStep} className={classes.stepper}>
            {steps.map((step) => (
              <Step key={step}>
                <StepLabel>{step}</StepLabel>
              </Step>
            ))}
          </Stepper>
          {activeStep === steps.length ? <Confirmation /> : <Form />}
        </Paper>
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Checkout;
```

**PaymentForm AND CheckoutForm, both in the same file**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Typography, Button, Divider } from '@material-ui/core';
import {
  Elements,
  CardElement,
  ElementsConsumer,
  useStripe,
  useElements,
} from '@stripe/react-stripe-js';
import { loadStripe } from '@stripe/stripe-js';
import axios from 'axios';

import { getTotal } from '../../helpers/helperTools';


import Review from './Review';

const stripePromise = loadStripe(
  'pk_HIDDEN_FOR_NOW'
);

const CheckoutForm = ({ shippingData, backStep, nextStep, setQty }) => {
  const stripe = useStripe();
  const elements = useElements();
  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (!stripe || !elements) {
      return;
    }

    const storageItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('product'));
    const products = storageItems || [];

    const totalPrice = getTotal(products);
    let productTitle = '';

    products.map((item, index) => {
      productTitle = `${productTitle} | ${item.title}`;
    });

    const cardElement = elements.getElement(CardElement);

    const { error, source } = await stripe.createSource(cardElement);
    console.log(error, source);
    const order = await axios.post('http://localhost:7000/api/stripe/charge', {
      amount: totalPrice * 100,
      source: source.id,
      receipt_email: shippingData.email,
      title: productTitle,
      customerName: `${shippingData.firstName} ${shippingData.lastName}`,
      address: {
        city: shippingData.City,
        country: shippingData.shippingCountry,
        line1: shippingData.address1,
        postal_code: shippingData.ZIP,
        state: shippingData.shippingState,
      },
    });

    if (error) {
      console.log('[error]', error);
    } else {
      console.log('[PaymentMethod]', order);
      localStorage.setItem('product', JSON.stringify([]));
      nextStep();
      setQty({quantity: 0});
    }
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <CardElement
        options={{
          style: {
            base: {
              fontSize: '16px',
              color: '#424770',
              '::placeholder': {
                color: '#aab7c4',
              },
            },
            invalid: {
              color: '#9e2146',
            },
          },
        }}
      />
      <div style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
        <Button variant='outlined' onClick={backStep}>
          Back
        </Button>
        <Button type='submit' variant='contained' disabled={!stripe} color='primary'>
          Pay
        </Button>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
};

function PaymentForm({ shippingData, backStep, nextStep, setQty }) {
  return (
    <Elements stripe={stripePromise}>
      <Review />
      <br />
      <br />
      <CheckoutForm shippingData={shippingData} nextStep={nextStep} backStep={backStep} setQty={setQty} />
    </Elements>
  );
}

export default PaymentForm;
```

**Screenshot of my file structure**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the App component, you need to pass `setQty` as below. Props that are mentioned in the Route component would not be transmitted to the component by itself, and we need to use the [render function](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/render-func) to pass props.

```
<Route path="/Checkout" render={(props) => <Checkout setQty={setQty} {...props}/>
```

Comment: You are correct, however I edited the line to this:
<Route path="/Checkout" render={(props) => <Checkout {...props} setQty={setQty} />} />
Thank you!